# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: author

```
function themeperauthor_need_switch() {
    global $post;
  if ( $get_post_type == 'weblogs' )  {
    return get_the_author_meta('themeperauthor', $user->ID);
  }
  return "";
}
```

It doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

You are using get_post_type as variable instead of a function try:

```
function themeperauthor_need_switch() {
    global $post;
  if ( get_post_type($post) == 'weblogs' )  {
    return get_the_author_meta('themeperauthor', $user->ID);
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to switch theme per author based on the given profile field by each author. So I need to get the author profile data `get_the_author_meta('themeperauthor', $user->ID);`

Comment: Suppose if I give-  return "twentyten"; than theme get switched but this code return `get_the_author_meta('themeperauthor', $user->ID);` doesn't show pull in any data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **@puanthanh:**

Well to start `$user` is not in scope.  But since you've given very few details I'm not sure how to suggest you assign a value.  Maybe update your question with more details?

Comment: I want to fetch the author data profile field name 'themeperauthor' Do I need to put this on the top `<?php
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
?>
` Will it fetch the author profile field data?

Comment: Thanks MikeSchinkel for pointing it out. my correct code now is `function themeperauthor_need_switch() {
    global $post; global $user_id;
$author_id=$post->post_author;
  if ( get_post_type($post) == 'weblogs' )  {
    return get_the_author_meta('themeperauthor', $author_id);
  }
  return "";
}` Thanks all. I am new here and I already like this site. English is my second lang. sorry about it

Comment: @puanthanh - To add code you should update your question or post your own answer. Code posting in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're aiming to do, but maybe..

```
function themeperauthor_need_switch() {
    global $post
    //, $current_user;
    if( !isset( $post->post_type ) )
        return '';
    if ( $post->post_type == 'weblogs' )
        return get_the_author_meta( 'themeperauthor', 
            $post->post_author
            //$current_user->ID
        );
    return '';
}
```

Assumed you want to get meta based on post author, but can be switched for the current user if that's actually what you want(left alternate lines in the code, but commented out).

**NOTE:** If using `$current_user`, you should check there's a user logged in first.. `if( is_user_logged_in() )` or similar..